# Is it possible in C# to open the registry of another computer as read-only without administrator rights?

Tags: c#, registry

Is it possible in C# to open the registry of another computer as read-only without administrator rights?  Specifically, I'd like to read LocalMachine/Software/...

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with C#; writing the program in C# doesn't change how the program interacts with the Windows security system.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to be a member of the `Local Administrators` group on the remote machine, and provide appropriate credentials for that account when trying to access the registry. The remote machine also has to be configured to allow that access.